# How can I loop through a table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I've created a table using javascript.

```
function tableCreate(){
  document.write("<table name= \"table\" >");
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     document.write("<tr>");
     for(j=0;j<n;j++){
       document.write("<td id=\"square"+k+"\">"+"</td>");
       k++;
     }
     document.write("</tr>");
   }
  document.write("</table>");
}
```

And with another function I've generated numbers in each cell ().
I want to loop through all td's of the table and get the value which is in it and the to put all the values in an array.

If needed here is the function to generate the numbers also:

```
function genNumbers(){
  for(i=0;i<=n*n;i++){
  var newNum =  Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxRand-minRand+1)+minRand);
  document.getElementById("square" + i).innerHTML = newNum;
  numArr[j] = newNum;
    j++;
  }
}
```

I really appreciate the help. And please if possible give the answer in javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: "not jQuery" - i wonder why, but anyway... After rendering the html DOM, why not just loop through array from something like document.getElementsByTagName("tr") and then inside each iteration for td... I mean sure it is completely doable, but jQuery just lifts off so much extra coding...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` to get a list of td elements.

Then just loop through them:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i< tds.length ; i++) {
    var td = tds[i];
    // do what you want with td
}
```

Comment: Yup, but in case there are extra tables inside cells, or the amount of columns is irregular, looping through just cell elements can get messy, in case you want to keep track, where you currently are in the table (row number, column number etc...)